# Android Layout Redrawn and Blurred

Tags: android, user-interface

I have a fairly standard layout that is initially rendered, but then gets blurred after being redrawn (e.g if the soft keyboard appears/disappears). Please see the referenced image.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/st7owe4964afks9/BlurredAndroidLayout.png

I thought the ScrollView may have been the culprit, but removing it did not have any effect.

Has anyone got any ideas on what I need to do to fix this?

Thanks

Here is the layout code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    tools:context=".CouncilMapServerMainActivity" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
            style="@style/MainPanel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/InfoGroupPanel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                tools:ignore="UselessParent" >
                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:layout_height="48dp" 
                    android:layout_width="48dp" 
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:cropToPadding="false"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/appName"
                    android:visibility="visible">
                </ImageView>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/appNameLabel"
                    android:text="@string/reportAProblemButtonLabel"
                    style="@style/AppTitleLabel"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/appTitleTextSize">
                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    style="@style/MainButtonPanel"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/reportAProblemFormWidth"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

                    <!-- Problem Type -->
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/reportAProblemProblemTypePrompt"
                        android:text="@string/reportAProblemProblemTypePrompt"
                        style="@style/OverTopPrompt"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/widgetLayoutMargin"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/infoGroupTitleTextSize">
                    </TextView>
                    <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/reportAProblemProblemSpinnerId"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:entries="@array/reportAProblemProblemTypeArray"
                            android:prompt="@string/reportAProblemProblemTypePrompt">
                    </Spinner>

                    <!-- Photo -->
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/reportAProblemPhotoPrompt"
                        android:text="@string/reportAProblemPhotoPrompt"
                        style="@style/OverTopPrompt"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/widgetLayoutMargin"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/infoGroupTitleTextSize">
                    </TextView>
                    <LinearLayout
                        style="@style/InfoGroupPanel"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        tools:ignore="UselessParent" >
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/reportAProblemTakePhotoButtonId"
                            android:text="@string/reportAProblemTakePhotoButtonLabel"
                            style="@style/ButtonBarButton"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/infoGroupTitleTextSize">
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/reportAProblemSelectPhotoButtonId"
                            android:text="@string/reportAProblemSelectPhotoButtonLabel"
                            style="@style/ButtonBarButton"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/infoGroupTitleTextSize">
                        </Button>
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                            android:layout_height="50dp" 
                            android:layout_width="50dp" 
                            android:layout_margin="0dp"
                            android:cropToPadding="false"
                            android:scaleType="centerInside"
                            android:contentDescription="@string/reportAProblemPhotoDescription"
                            android:visibility="visible">
                        </ImageView>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <!-- Location -->
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/reportAProblemLocationPrompt"
                        android:text="@string/reportAProblemLocationPrompt"
                        style="@style/OverTopPrompt"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/widgetLayoutMargin"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/infoGroupTitleTextSize">
                    </TextView>
                    <LinearLayout
                        style="@style/InfoGroupPanel"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        tools:ignore="UselessParent" >
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/reportAProblemPickFromMapButtonId"
                            android:text="@string/reportAProblemPickFromMapButtonLabel"
                            style="@style/ButtonBarButton"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/infoGroupTitleTextSize">
                        </Button>
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/reportAProblemSelectedLocationTextId"
                            android:text="@string/reportAProblemSelectedLocationText"
                            android:layout_gravity="top"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="@dimen/widgetLayoutMargin"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/infoGroupTitleTextSize">
                        </TextView>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <!-- Description -->
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/reportAProblemDescriptionPrompt"
                        android:text="@string/reportAProblemDescriptionPrompt"
                        style="@style/OverTopPrompt"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/widgetLayoutMargin"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/infoGroupTitleTextSize">
                    </TextView>
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/reportAProblemDescriptionEditTextId"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                        android:lines="@integer/reportAProblemDesriptionLineCount"
                        style="@style/ButtonBarButton"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/infoGroupTitleTextSize">
                    </EditText>

                    <!-- Name -->
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/reportAProblemNamePrompt"
                        android:text="@string/reportAProblemNamePrompt"
                        style="@style/OverTopPrompt"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/widgetLayoutMargin"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/infoGroupTitleTextSize"
                        >
                    </TextView>
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/reportAProblemNameEditTextId"
                        android:inputType="textPersonName|textAutoComplete"
                        style="@style/ButtonBarButton"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/widgetLayoutMargin"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/infoGroupTitleTextSize">
                    </EditText>

                    <!-- Email -->
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/reportAProblemEmailPrompt"
                        android:text="@string/reportAProblemEmailPrompt"
                        style="@style/OverTopPrompt"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/widgetLayoutMargin"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/infoGroupTitleTextSize">
                    </TextView>
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/reportAProblemEmailEditTextId"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textAutoComplete"
                        style="@style/ButtonBarButton"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/widgetLayoutMargin"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/infoGroupTitleTextSize">
                    </EditText>

                    <!-- Phone -->
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/reportAProblemPhonePrompt"
                        android:text="@string/reportAProblemPhonePrompt"
                        style="@style/OverTopPrompt"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/widgetLayoutMargin"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/infoGroupTitleTextSize">
                    </TextView>
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/reportAProblemPhoneEditTextId"
                        android:inputType="phone|textAutoComplete"
                        style="@style/ButtonBarButton"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/widgetLayoutMargin"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/infoGroupTitleTextSize">
                    </EditText>

                    <LinearLayout
                        style="@style/InfoGroupPanel"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        tools:ignore="UselessParent" >
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/reportAProblemSubmitButtonId"
                            android:text="@string/reportAProblemSubmitButtonLabel"
                            style="@style/ButtonBarButton"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/infoGroupTitleTextSize">
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/reportAProblemClearButtonId"
                            android:text="@string/reportAProblemClearButtonLabel"
                            style="@style/ButtonBarButton"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/infoGroupTitleTextSize">
                        </Button>
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Doesn't really look like a blur...more like drawn on top of the old layout a second time.

Comment: We need to see the layout code.

Comment: Provide more details (see comment above mine), or else this may be qualified as vague, ambiguous and incomplete question that can't be answered in its current form. That will bring the Axes of Evil to your question, and you don't want that. :P

Comment: Maybe your backgrounds are transparent, set an opaque color

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I worked it to be a style issue. I had the following:

```
<style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="appTitleLabelStyle">@style/AppTitleLabel</item>
    <item name="buttonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```

Removing the following line fixed the problem (but I don't know why):

```
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
```